# Blackberry How to play sound (short[]) using the speaker of the device?

Tags: blackberry, audio, java-me, rim-4.5, rim-5.0

I am using [Alert.startAudio](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html) to play an array of short values, 
I want the same `short[]` to be played using the phone speaker, how could I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is played with speaker by default!
But if it's not, try to use [AudioPathControl](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/media/control/AudioPathControl.html)

See [BB KB How To - Specify Audio Path Routing](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Specify_Audio_Path_Routing.html?nodeid=1326675&vernum=0)

**UPDATE**
[BB Developer Journals - The BlackBerry Alert Class](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devjournals/resources/journals/sep_2006/alert.jsp):

> The next two methods will start and stop an audio alert on the audio channel **selected by the user**. An audio channel can be the internal headset, speaker, earpiece or a Bluetooth® headset.

maybe this should be configured somewhere in device...

Comment: The code you sent to plays an MP3. It's not the same case here. Alert.StartAudio plays an array of short, i want to play the same short[] using the device speaker, not playing an MP3 file. Because ALert.StartAudio doesn't use the speaker but i want the same data sent to Alert.StartAudio (the short[]) to be played using the device speaker.